# Audio Glitch in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I've fully developed an audio player that plays a radio station's stream. They currently host their audio on StreamOn and when you click the play button in the player in the lower right of the streaming widget the audio, after buffering, plays via inserting an iframe that is styled to be invisible. However, people on staff have complained that if you click on the play button multiple times whilst it's loading, it will play multiple streams (as can be seen here: [Glitched Page](http://wpovfm.org)). So, on my test page I attempted the below code to prevent such scenarios from occuring. However, audio isn't even being loaded on requested now (as can be seen here: [Test Page](http://wpovfm.org/moldycheese/index.php)). Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
                $playing = 0;

                $(document).on("click", "button#mute", function(){
                    $('iframe#audioStreamOn').remove();
                    $playing = 0;
                });

                if ($playing =0) {
                    $(document).on("click", "button#play", function(){
                        $(this).after('<iframe id="audioStreamOn" class="hidden" src="http://wpov.streamon.fm"></iframe>');
                        $playing = 1;
                    });
                }

                else {
                    $(document).on("click", "button#play", function(){
                    });
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change your code a bit. On your Glitched page you have this:

```
$(document).on("click", "button#mute", function () {
    $('iframe#audioStreamOn').remove();
});
$(document).on("click", "button#play", function () {
    $(this).after('<iframe id="audioStreamOn" class="hidden" src="http://wpov.streamon.fm"></iframe>');
});
```

Use this instead:

```
var playing = 0;
$(document).on("click", "button#mute", function () {
    $('iframe#audioStreamOn').remove();
    playing = 0;
});
$(document).on("click", "button#play", function () {
    if (playing == 0) {
        $(this).after('<iframe id="audioStreamOn" class="hidden" src="http://wpov.streamon.fm"></iframe>');
        playing = 1;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

What I changed:

- You had `if ($playing =0) {` this will not check the value it will assign it, you need `==` to compare them. I also removed the `$`, $ in javascript is good practise to not have in variables, and here it's even used by jQuery.
- I changed your click event listeners to wrap your `if` statement. You had the other way around. Like this, when play button is clicked it will check the `if` statement. Your `if` statement was just being checked on page load and no function was calling it again.
- in your `else` I just have `return false;` now, which means if `playing == 1`, don't do anything (ignore the click).